# How to append a variable declarion into a specefic function at runtime using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i append a declaration of a variable at run time inside a function using jquery. Do we have something like selecting a specific function and appending line of statements like we do with elements.

Comment: I have a function **footer_Reload** which needs to be called whenever any ajax call have been made to database, and in that i need to append this line of statement at ***footer_Reload*** on the success of ajax call. So my footer will again check that is there any content on the body.

Comment: Can't you just rewrite your `footer_Reload()` function with some conditional logic? Adding a new variable declaration into a function really doesn't make sense because how would the rest of the function know to use that variable? In any case I don't believe JS allows you to modify a function after it's declared, though you could _replace_ the entire function with one that includes the changes you "need".